# how to prevent flextable to add Table #: in front of the caption using bookdown and word output Lua

Tags: r, lua, markdown, cpu-word, flextable

I am struggling to remove the "Table 1:" string in front of my flextable.

All the options provided on the internet do not really work as expected. So for example using `|# tab.cap.pre:`  empty or at least something different.

My last idea was using `Lua` filters, but somehow I do not understand the panic AST good enough the remove this string.

Example markdown would be:

````
---
title: ""
output:
   bookdown::word_document2:
    pandoc_args:
      - --lua-filter=custom_header.lua
---

# test
```{r,  echo=FALSE}
library(flextable)
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
abb <-
  data.frame(
    Abbrevation=c("AU"),
    Meaning=c("Absorbance Unit")
  )
flextable(abb) |>
  set_caption('my test')
```
````

My Lua filter file looks currently like this:

```
function Table(el)
  el.caption = string.gsub(el.caption, 'Table ', '')
  return el
end
```

So somehow I am not sure if `el.caption` is correct. How do I figure out which methods my `el` has? I am completely stuck with debugging some Lua functions.

**EDIT**

I have to ask that question again. After nobody had a suggestion with the LUA filters, I tried to implement David Gohels solution, even if it is less readable in my opinion.

Problem which now occurs is, if I remove the `set_caption` command, I can't get the actual table number for a link.

````
---
title: ""
output:
   bookdown::word_document2
---

# test
```{r,  echo=FALSE}
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
```

look at [Table \@ref(tab:test1)](#linkTEST)

::: {custom-style="Table Caption"}

my test `r date()`

::: 

:::{#linkTEST}
```{r test1, echo=FALSE}
abb <-
  data.frame(
    Abbrevation=c("AU"),
    Meaning=c("Absorbance Unit")
  )
flextable(abb) %>% 
  set_caption('test')
```
:::
````

So if I remove the `%>% set_caption('text')` the number of the table can't be retrieved and the link is named `Table ??`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is added automatically by bookdown. Best in your case would be to not use captions so that they are not treated by bookdown and to add manually yours (with pandoc attribute) - in the paragraph definition, you can also add r expression as it will be managed by knitr.

````
---
title: ""
output:
   bookdown::word_document2
---

# test
```{r,  echo=FALSE}
library(flextable)
```

::: {custom-style="Table Caption"}

my test `r date()`

::: 

```{r echo=FALSE}
abb <-
  data.frame(
    Abbrevation=c("AU"),
    Meaning=c("Absorbance Unit")
  )
flextable(abb)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Hi David, thanks, this seems to work, however, I can't have interactive captions then... for example replacing `my test` with `r cat(date())`  (in back ticks) does not really work. I don't get any output

Comment: This is knitr syntax, not flextable. use `r date()` instead

Comment: Could you update your code to include this, it seems not to work or I do not understand...

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I would still prefer a Lua solution, but can't get it running. Your solution helps for now!

Comment: I thought that `lua` filters were only recommended as a last option. Why do you want `lua`?

Comment: I have the feeling, adding blocks makes the whole RMD difficult to read... I have the feeling it is more straight forward to just go through the table captions and remove a single word and number at the beginning... And I think `lua` not to be the last option, but it gets applied last. I just don't understand it :-D

Comment: ahhhhr, I can't argue against feelings :) Have a good learning

Comment: Hi David, I have to ask that question again. Since I didn't found a LUA solution I tried to implement your suggestion. My problem is now. I want to create links to the table with table number. And markdown can't get the correct table number unless I use `set_caption`. Any suggestion?